# Covering roof vents to keep out roof rats

Tags: roof, vent, exhaust-vent

I have around 20 vents on my roof and I currently do not have a roof rat problem but I want to cover them with something to prevent roof rats getting into the attic. I'm sure I can find something at home depot that will do this and still allow the air passage through the netting/mesh that I put over the vents.

My question is about the vent that is used for the dryer. Lint coming out of that vent can attach itself to the covering and create a fire hazard. Is there a safe way to prevent rats from getting into the dryer through this vent?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a roof cat!

Comment: What kind of vents? Attic vents? Do you have a picture?

Comment: I actually don't think this can be done legally.  Especially on a roof, where you will have difficulty getting up to clean it.   Your best bet might be to extend the duct a few feet above the roofline to make the vent inaccessible to rats.

Answer (score 2):

Dryer vents are often equipped with covers that have [louvers](http://www.lowes.com/pd_433271-131-433271_0__?productId=4566286&Ntt=dryer%20vent&pl=1&currentURL=?Ntt=dryer%2bvent&facetInfo=), such as this one

[image: louvered vent]

While a determined animal might squeeze through or gnaw a hole, it offers some protection.

There are also alternatives that use a spring loaded or weighted round flap under a [cover](http://www.lowes.com/pd_328919-85334-VTL0036_0__?productId=4177177&Ntt=dryer%20vent&pl=1&currentURL=?Ntt=dryer%2bvent&page=2&facetInfo=), like this one

[image: weighted vent]

Again, same issues. They come in metal and plastic.  The metal may be a bit more animal proof.